# 2 routers on home network

Tags: router, home-networking

This may seem like a silly problem my current setup is as follows:

DSL => Router1 (192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0) => Router2 (192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0)

Both work fine, and both dish out there own set of ip addresses. Router2 has no problem accessing the computers hooked up to router1, but router1 can't access any of the machines on router2.

While I could make router2 act like a hub and just leave everything to router1, I'd rather router2 handle and organize its own network traffic.

Anyone know of a way that I can fix router2 though so that router1 can see and or talk to it?

Comment: Is router2 doing any NATing?

Comment: What would be very useful is if you could post the configs. then we can see what they are currently doing.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you would have to add a static route to to **Router1** that forwards all traffic for 192.168.0.0/24 to the external interface of **Router2**.

Of course, **Router2** would have to be configured to accept packets on its interface on the 192.168.1.x network. If **Router2** is using NAT, which I assume it's not, then you would require additional configuration steps like port forwarding.

Comment: any advice on how i'd go about doing this?

Comment: This is different for each router. What routers do you have?

Comment: linksys wrtgl running tomato and dlink dir-655